# The program can't start because sqlite3.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, dll

Every time I start my computer I get this error.

[image]

I tried to find `PluginInstall.exe` in my process or startup and there's nothing there.

[image]

I ran Avast anti virus as well and there was no virus.

I searched my whole computer for `PluginInstall.exe` and nothing shows either, so before downloading the sqlite3.dll and dropping it in my windows folder I wanted to find out what this program is or where is it, etc..

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try MS' [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) for checking what starts with Windows; it shows you way more info than MSconfig.

Comment: You need to determine which startup entry is causing the error.  The best way is trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PluginInstall.exe is in your AutoStart folder. It seems to use sqlite.

```
C:\Program Files\IObit\Surfing Protection\PluginInstall.exe
```

Something like that. It is a common Malware. Sometimes Malware authors work sloppily. Then you are lucky and you get this error message.